# asp.net core 2.1 SecurityStampValidatorOptions ValidationInterval - works local, probelms in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a website built in asp.net core 2.1 with users in different roles. When I add or remove a role for a user, I want this to change his allowed behaviour accordingly.

What I did:

In the `Startup.cs` I added the following line in the `ConfigureServices`-function:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

When I execute the website **locally via Visual Studio**, everything works as expected: After at most 20 seconds the changed roles take effect, so that I have the rights matching the current roles. It doesn't matter, if these changes were done via `UserManager.RemovefromRolesAsync(user, "rolename")`, or by manually changing the roles in the underlying database.

Now I **publish the website to IIS** (v10 on Windows Server 2016). After 20 seconds the changed roles take effect exactly once. When I now navigate to any other page (before the next 20 seconds interval has passed), I suddenly see everything like it was before. `User.IsInRole("rolename")` for example now gives back a `true` value, even if I just removed that role beforehand. 20 seconds later it is again false exactly once.

Does anyone have any idea, why this code could behave differently in the IIS context?

For context: I have in my database tables for User, Role, UserRole and have a username/passwort authentication as basis. But the customer would like to be automatically logged in with windows authentication (intranet only website), while still using the roles as defined in the database, ignoring any roles from the active directory. I did this by checking if the currently logged on user is a `WindowsPrincipal`, which will then be newly logged in with the database-centric user.

**Edit**: The faulty behaviour isn't dependent on Visual Studio (IIS Express) vs IIS. I published it to an IIS on localhost and everything is still working. So localhost => OK, remote (but intranet) => problems. This is consistent across browsers, so I assume it is not a configuration in the browser.

Comment: Are different settings taking effect in IIS (like the ASPNETENVIRONMENT is "Production" instead of "Development") and then different settings (e.g. caching roles in cookies) being used instead?

Comment: @MartinCostello I just checked my source code. None of the places where I check the current environment will lead to anything related to caching, cookies or the like. When I start the project with the config for IIS Express Production (which sets the variable to "Production"), everything still is working as expected.